# MongoDB C# driver - how to query a property on an array of subdocuments

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

Let's suppose I have the following document structure in MongoDB.

```
{
    _id: ####,
    Ancestors: [
        { _id: 1, Name: "asdf" },
        { _id: 2, Name: "jkl;" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to find every document that contains an Ancestor where _id of the Ancestor is 2.

I can run this query in the mongo shell using this:  `db.projects.find({"Ancestors._id": 2})`

I can also run this query using the official C# driver using this:  `Query.EQ("Ancestors._id", new BsonInt32(rootProjectId))`.

Here are my POCOs; the actual classes I'm using have more properties than this, but I didn't want to clutter up the question with unnecessary details:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectRef> Ancestors { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRef
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is:  How can I write a strongly-typed query using the C# driver so that I don't have to pass in "Ancestors._id" as a string?  I want to be able to do something like `Query<Project>.EQ(p => p.Id, rootProjectId)` so that I can instead use a member expression and let the class mappings tell the driver that it should use "Ancestors._id".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB + C# driver + query array of elements where each array element contains sub-document to query on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024087/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-query-array-of-elements-where-each-array-element-cont)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ElemMatch** is your friend in this case.

try the following:

```
var ancestorsQuery = Query<ProjectRef>.EQ(pr => pr.Id, rootProjectId);
var finalQuery = Query<Project>.ElemMatch(p => p.Ancestors, builder => ancestorsQuery));
```

use finalQuery within a Find command on the Projects collection.

Comment: The query builder supplied to the second parameter of `Query<>.ElemMatch()` is typed by the first parameter, so if you want to write the whole query as a single statement, you can do: `var finalQuery = Query<Project>.ElemMatch(p => p.Ancestors, builder => builder.EQ(pr => pr.Id, rootProjectId));` and save a couple keystrokes.

Comment: any idea why would positional operator wont work by using this way?