# Composite pattern abstraction. Persistence. Querying hierarchical data

Tags: c#, mongodb, tree, composite

Let's say I want to model my domain using the composite pattern. The model ([gist](https://gist.github.com/abirdd/8978761ae8566a98aaec#file-model-cs)) is fairly simple. At album controller I want to perform a search on a given name:

```
public ActionResult Edit(String name) {
    if(name == null) {
        ViewBag.ViewRoot = true;
        return View(this.albums.All());
    }

    var album = this.albums.Single(a => a.Name == name);
    if(album != null) {
        ViewBag.ViewRoot = false;
        return View(album.Yield());
    }

    return View("404", (Object)("Album:" + name));
}
```

The resulting (filtered) persisted object looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "52ab1a6a7b88c91e5cfc39ff",
    "ParentId" : null,
    "Name" : "sample01",
    "Items" : [{
        "_t" : "Album",
        "_id" : null,
        "ParentId" : "52ab1a6a7b88c91e5cfc39ff",
        "Name" : "sample02",
        "Items" : [{
            "_t" : "Album",
            "_id" : null,
            "ParentId" : null,
            "Name" : "sample03",
            "Items" : []
        }]
    }]
}
```

Mongodb doesn't perform recursive search out of the box. But it allows you to perform queries given that you provide an explicit `direction` (code sample is taken from [MongoDB + C# driver + query array of elements where each array element contains sub-document to query on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024087/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-query-array-of-elements-where-each-array-element-cont)):

```
Query.ElemMatch("Children", Query.And(Query.EQ("StatusId", 1), Query.EQ("Active", true),Query.LT("SubChild.ExpiresOn", DateTime.UtcNow)));
```

I've been thinking about two solutions (which might keep it `composite`):

- tracking the node depth (then I should build complicated query);
- use parent sign (id, name), fetch entire graph, then perform recursive search at the client side.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you trying to model a tree hierarchy? @brick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some design patterns for modelling tree structures in `mongodb` among them being :

- Parent References
- Child References
- Array of Ancestors
- Materialised Paths
- Nested Sets

for me it sounds like you need a tree structure with materialised paths, but you can have a look at [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) for further information about the available design patterns used for similar issues

Comment: If I understand it right the thought behind using materialized path is that you attach an array of identifiers of existsing entities. Is that right? Then it sowewhat breaks idea of composite pattern.

Comment: @brick materialised path is that you specify the path of the document in the path field.I am not talking about the composite pattern here, I just suggested you to store your tree structure efficiently so you dont need to perform recursive queries

Comment: Yes I understand that. And I've been thinking about `MP`. But I'm focused on the pattern. Is it no good when it comes to persistance? So you should use techniques mentioned above?

Comment: @brick I think that modelling your persistence properly is much important than the pattern, you can always change the pattern. If your data is persisted properly you can do whatever you want efficiently

Comment: That's true about efficiency. Thank you for your input.