# MongoDb c# driver find item in array by field value

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

i found the way to check is the value contains in simple array :

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.AnyEq(x => x.Tags, "mongodb");
```

But how to find a complex item with many fields by a concrete field ?
I found the way to write it via the dot notation approach with `BsonDocument` builder, but how can i do it with typed lambda notations ?

**upd**

i think it some kind of

```
builderInst.AnyIn(p => p.ComplexCollection.Select(ml => ml.Id), mlIds)
```

but can't check right now, is anyone could help ?

Comment: Looks like a homework from MongoDb University.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB + C# driver + query array of elements where each array element contains sub-document to query on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024087/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-query-array-of-elements-where-each-array-element-cont)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is `ElemMatch`

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Tags, x => x.Name == "test");
var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: @shiva8 You can not user `AnyIn` when you have array of complex objects.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an example that returns a single complex item from an array (using MongoDB.Driver v2.5.0):

**Simple Data Model**

```
public class Zoo
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 1 (Aggregation)**

```
public Animal FindAnimalInZoo(string animalName)
{
    var zooWithAnimalFilter = Builders<Zoo>.Filter
        .ElemMatch(z => z.Animals, a => a.Name == animalName);

    return _db.GetCollection<Zoo>("zoos").Aggregate()
        .Match(zooWithAnimalFilter)
        .Project<Animal>(
            Builders<Zoo>.Projection.Expression<Animal>(z => 
                z.Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == animalName)))
        .FirstOrDefault(); // or .ToList() to return multiple
}
```

**Option 2 (Filter & Linq)** This was about 5x slower for me

```
public Animal FindAnimalInZoo(string animalName)
{
    // Same as above
    var zooWithAnimalFilter = Builders<Zoo>.Filter
        .ElemMatch(z => z.Animals, a => a.Name == animalName);

    var zooWithAnimal = _db.GetCollection<Zoo>("zoos")
        .Find(zooWithAnimalFilter)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return zooWithAnimal.Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == animalName);
}
```

Comment: Any idea on why the second option is (about 5x) slower than the first one?

Answer (score 8):

You need the `$elemMatch` operator. You could use `Builders<T>.Filter.ElemMatch` or an `Any` expression:

```
Find(x => x.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "test")).ToListAsync()
```

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/expressions/#elemmatch

Comment: Warning, Any() doesn't work when targeting Azure CosmosDB - see https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/33755596-support-dot-notation-with-mongodb

Answer (score 4):

As of the 2.4.2 release of the C# drivers, the IFindFluent interface can be used for querying on array element.  ElemMatch cannot be used on an array of strings directly, whereas the find interface will work on either simple or complex types (e.g. 'Tags.Name') and is strongly typed.

```
            FilterDefinitionBuilder<Post> tcBuilder = Builders<Post>.Filter;
            FilterDefinition<Post> tcFilter = tcBuilder.Eq("Tags","mongodb") & tcBuilder.Eq("Tags","asp.net");
               ...
            await myCollection.FindAsync(tcFilter);
```

Linq driver uses the aggregation framework, but for a query with no aggregation operators a find is faster.

Note that this has been broken in previous versions of the driver so the answer was not available at the time of original posting.

Comment: Hello Aaron, your solution had fixed my problem.However, i would like to know the performance of this, if there are close to a lakh records.