# MongoDB C# Driver Find Object which contains an Object in a List with multiple properties that meets certain criteria

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have mongo objects that follows the following pattern. Tags is an array of objects.

```
{
  "id" : "123",
  ...
  "Tags" : [{
      ...
      "first_name" : "jack",
      "last_name" : "john",
      "alive" : true 
  }]  
}
```

How do I query this so that I can get a list of objects which contain an object in the tags array who's first_name property and last_name property matches a given string  using the C# Mongo Driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb c# driver find item in array by field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786220/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-find-item-in-array-by-field-value)

Comment: No, its not. I tried the solution provided in the link mentioned by @Aman. But it returns objects which contain one object whose first_name matches but last_name and another object whose last_name matches but first_name

Comment: you can do an and filter

Comment: `Builders<Post>.Filter.And( firstnameFilter, lastNameFilter);`