# How do i filter through a MongoDB Array with C# to return only the specific records that i need

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

My query.

```
public List<T> GetETrannsfer<T>(string table, string Branch, string userName, string status)
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.And(Builders<T>.Filter.Regex("Branch", new BsonRegularExpression("/^" + Branch + "$/i")),
                Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("eLogInfo.userName", userName),
                Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("eLogInfo.status", status));
            return collection.Find(filter).ToList();
        }
```

My EquipmentLogModel

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class EquipmentLogModel
    {

        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string eLogType { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
        public EquipmentLogInfoModel[] eLogInfo { get; set; }

    }
```

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class EquipmentLogInfoModel
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string eModel { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public string eDescription { get; set; }
        public string serialNum { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

If one object in the array contains the filtered variables MongoDB sends me a result of all objects in the array.
I only need the objects that contains the specific variables.

so i tried to use ElemMatch as suggested i still get the same results the records do not get filtered the results contain all the records under the specific array.

```
public EquipmentLogModel GetETrannsfer(string table, string Branch, string userName, string status)
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<EquipmentLogModel>(table);
            var filter = Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.And(Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.Regex("Branch", new BsonRegularExpression("/^" + Branch + "$/i")),
               Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.eLogInfo, x => x.status == status),
               Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.eLogInfo, x => x.userName == userName));
            return collection.Find(filter).First();

        }
```

i also tried the below, it returned only one record which i need more than one, and i am unable to filter the return by more than one variable.

```
 public EquipmentLogInfoModel GetETrannsfer(string table, string Branch, string userName, string status)
        {
            var filter = Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.And(Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.Regex("Branch", new BsonRegularExpression("/^" + Branch + "$/i")),
               Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.eLogInfo, x => x.status == status),
               Builders<EquipmentLogModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.eLogInfo, x => x.userName == userName));

            var collection = db.GetCollection<EquipmentLogModel>(table).Find(filter)
               .FirstOrDefault();

            return collection.eLogInfo.FirstOrDefault(a => a.userName == userName);
        }
```

Comment: Use elemMatch. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786220/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-find-item-in-array-by-field-value/31799697

Comment: hi i tried to do this Builders<T>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.eLogInfo, x => x._id == id));  but T doesn't contain definition for eLogInfo, i am not sure how to make the ElemMatch work with the syntax that i am using. Error is T doesn't contain a definition for eLogInfo

Comment: I could switch from T to the actual model but then that says i cannot convert from my model to T..Could you please use my example method above and show me an example of how i would use the ElemMatch

Comment: please see updated above the code i tried.

Comment: When you say, "objects that contains the specific variables." do you mean you only need specific fields? If so, have you tried 'Projection' like   collection.Find(filter)
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id").Include("<your-specific-fields>"))
        .ToList();

Comment: No I mean the object that I store in the array of objects...I want to say select all objects from 10 present objects withing that array based on the username and status that has been Provided by the user...so if 5 object from the 10 matches with the username and status give me those 5 object not all 10

Comment: @raga
 can you help?