# How to search in mongodb nested array using c# driver

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, nested

does anybody know to to search in nested array using c# driver for mongodb ?

For example:
I have a list of documents of type Person. An example of Person entity is the following

```
 {
    "Name": "HumanName",
    "Occupation": "Student",
    "Class": [
        {
            "ClassType": "Math",
            "Professors": [
                {
                    "Name": "Jimmy"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Smith"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ClassType": "English",
            "Professors": [
                {
                    "Name": "John"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i write a query that will bring me all the documents with Occupation Student, Class Math  and Professor Smith ?

I tried with elemMatch something like the following but it doesn't work

```
        var builder = Builders<Person>.Filter;
        var filters = builder.Eq(x => x.Occupation, "Student");

        filters = filters & builder.ElemMatch(x => x.Class, x=> x.ClassType =="Math");
        filters = filters & builder.ElemMatch(x => x.Class[-1].Professors, x=> x.Name =="Smith");

        var result = await Mongo.Persons.Find(filters).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024087/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-query-array-of-elements-where-each-array-element-cont

Answer (score 0):

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Person>("Person");
var list = collection.AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => x.Ocupation == "Student" 
                     && x.Class.Any(y => y.ClassType == "Math" 
                     && y.Proffessors.Any(z => z.Name == "Smith")))
            .ToList();
```